# How to use [role=option] on anchors and buttons

Tags: html, listbox, accessibility, wai-aria

### `a[role=option]`

```
<div role="listbox">
    <a role="option">orange</a>
    <a role="option">purple</a>
</div>
```

> Error: Bad value `option` for attribute `role` on element `a`.

### `button[role=option]`

```
<div role="listbox">
    <button role="option">orange</button>
    <button role="option">purple</button>
</div>
```

> Error: Bad value `option` for attribute `role` on element `button`.

### `span[role=option]`

```
<div role="listbox">
    <span role="option">orange</span>
    <span role="option">purple</span>
</div>
```

Validates okay with spans. Based on the [`listbox` documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles#listbox) I'd think that `a[role=option]` or `button[role=option]` would be valid but those both give validation errors. They are sensible semantic fallbacks...why aren't they valid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither `a` nor `button` allow `role="option"`. This is by design. [There is a handy table](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-aria/) that outlines what roles are allowed on what elements ([so no `a`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-aria/#ahref) and [no `button`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-aria/#button)).

However, I recommend against doing this. Unless you are prepared to *exactly* mimic all the functionality of a `select` (all keyboard interactions, for example). Some [issues and examples are at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_listbox_role#Possible_effects_on_user_agents_and_assistive_technology) which includes some of the additional roles and functions you must put in place. ARIA was created as a bridge technology, not to replace native controls.

Comment: This is no longer true. Looking at the linked table now both `a` and `button` allow `role="option"` I believe this was changed in ARIA 1.1.

Answer (score 2):

The document pointed by @aardrian (see [Document conformance requirements for use of ARIA attributes](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-aria/#docconformance)) indicates that an **"[a element without a href](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-aria/#anohref)" may have "any role"**. So this could be valid as long as you satisfy the other condition:

> Authors must ensure elements with role option are contained in, or owned by, an element with the role listbox.

There is here a problem with the tool you used to validate your document.

For the `button` element, you are restricted to the following roles:
`checkbox`, `link`, `menuitem`, `menuitemcheckbox`, `menuitemradio`, `radio`, or `switch`. And so the error, is predictable.